# Javascript convert three arrays to one for use with AngularJS directive

Tags: arrays, angularjs, loops, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a $http call with which I retrieve an array of objects. I make three calls to this endpoint and end up with three arrays like the following:

```
[
  {type: Dog, count: 3}
  {type: Cat, count: 4}
  {type: Elephant, count: 1}
]
[
  {type: Dog, count: 1}
  {type: Cat, count: 9}
]
[
  {type: Dog, count: 19}
  {type: Cat, count: 4}
  {type: Elephant, count: 12}
  {type: Frog, count: 2}

]
```

The first call is for August stats, the second September, the third October.

What I would like is to then create a dataset that looks like this...

```
[
  {type:Dog, data:[3,1,9]}
  {type:Cat, data:[4,9,4]}
  {type:Elephant, data:[1. null, 12]}
  {type:Frog, data:[null, null, 2}
]
```

... so that I can loop through each element with an ngRepeat to display a table of Months/Animals stats.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to make 3 calls and data structure from server is different than what you are using in angular have used the `$q.all` to make sure all requests made before merging results. One challenge is that not all animals get returned each month. This took some extra coding to be able to show `0` if animal doesn't exist in amonth.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('DataService', function($http, $q) {
  /* temp object */
  var tmp = {}, resultsArray = [];


  var DataService = {
    animals: [],
    loadData: function() {

      var def = $q.defer();
      var deferreds = [];
      var requestUrl = ['data1.json', 'data2.json', 'data3.json'];
      for (i = 0; i < requestUrl.length; i++) {    
        var url = requestUrl[i];
        var request = $http.get(url).success(function(res) {
          resultsArray.push(res);

        });
        deferreds.push(request);
      }

      $q.all(deferreds).then(function() {
        def.resolve( mergeResults());
      })

      return def.promise
    }

  }


  function createCountArray() {
    var len = resultsArray.length,
      arr = [];
    while (len) {
      arr.push(0);
      len--
    }
    return arr
  }

  function mergeResults() {
    angular.forEach(resultsArray, function(arr, i) {
      /* create key for all animals, need this because not all animals in each result set */
      angular.forEach(arr, function(item) {
        if (!tmp[item.type]) {
          tmp[item.type] = {type: item.type,count: createCountArray() }
        }
      });
    });

    angular.forEach(resultsArray, function(arr, i) {
      /* now populate counts*/
      angular.forEach(arr, function(item) {
        tmp[item.type].count[i] = item.count;
      });
    });

    /* now map object to array*/

    angular.forEach(tmp, function(val) {
      DataService.animals.push(val);
    });

    return DataService.animals;
  }
  return DataService;

})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, DataService) {

  DataService.loadData().then(function(res) {
    $scope.animalData = res;
  });    

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/fXjehmZAFIGSQl3zOHI8?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks Charlie, was using $q already for the $http calls, but the mergeResults() function works well. Added a function to sort by the values in the count array in the animals array too, so all is good. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is some kind of groupBy operation - you can do your own research using this keyword. My suggestions are:

- use Javascript's native `concat()` to merge 3 arrays into one
- use `_.groupBy()` function from [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#groupBy) on merged array.
  This will do the grouping for you.
- iterate over resulting object to *map* results according to your needs; Underscore.js `_.map()` comes in hand

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/pZ2RR/) code snippet is a quick **demo** of what can be achieved. It works on already merged array.

Comment: Cheers Michael, the _.groupBy() defo looks like it should do it. Thanks for the fiddle.